# Настройка MTA sendmail

Tags: ubuntu, smtp, sendmail

Я установил на свой сервер(ubuntu 16) sendmail. Настроил файл конфигурации на smtp.google.com и ящик googl`a . Почта отправляется. Все хорошо. Но Я хочу отправлять почту со своего сервера. То есть хочу развернуть smtp на своём сервере и на него настроить агент. Как это сделать?

И второй вопрос. Как через smtp отправлять письма с разных ящиков, то есть подменять Mail-From в заголовках. (отправлять с сайта). И если нельзя через smtp то как возможно?

Comment: *Как это сделать?* — убрать вот это: «Настроил файл конфигурации на smtp.google.com и ящик googl`a» // несвязанные вопросы надо задавать по отдельности.

Comment: ну и вообще использование в наши времена программы *sendmail* в качестве [*mta*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80) чем-то сродни использованию (к примеру) [*ford model t*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_Model_T): ездить-то, пожалуй, будет, но если вдруг «что не так», то обращаться с вопросами и за помощью просто не к кому. гораздо практичнее будет установить что-нибудь более распространённое: *exim*, там, или *postfix*

Comment: @alexanderbarakin согласен с вами, поставлю postfix

Comment: "почту с сайта c подменой mail-from" - для этого я использую PHPMailer.